# How do I find a basis for this vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Let $S$ be any set and $F$ be any field.
$F^S$ is the set of all functions $f:S\to F$.
We can assume $F^S$ is a vector space over $F$. We have defined vector additions as:$(f+g)(s)=f(s)+g(s)$
and scalar multiplication as $(kf)(s)=kf(s)$.

When $S=\{a,b,c\}$, find a basis for $F^S$.

I don't quite understand how to approach this question or begin it. Are there not a hypothetical infinite amount of functions that are a part of $F^S$?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: There are infinitely many elements in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$. Doesn't prevent us from finding a basis for it...

Comment: Consider functions which are zero on all but one element of the set.

Comment: Also look up construction of free modules, this will help immensely

Comment: If $S$ is finite, then the functions $f_s$ with $f_s(s)=1$ and $f_s(t)=0$ for $t \ne s$ form a basis of $F^S$. However, if $S$ is infinite, then those functions form a basis not for $F^S$ (all functions) but rather for the subset of finitely supported functions (those functions $f$ for which there are only finitely many $s \in S$ for which $f(s) \ne 0$).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm going to do this in generality, and leave you to apply it to the case where $S=\{a,b,c\}$. Let $S$ be any set (even an uncountably large set!), and consider the set:
$$F^S=\{f:S\rightarrow F: f(s)= 0 \text{ for all but finitely many }s\in S\}$$
Then we have that $F^S$ is clearly a vector space (which is exactly the same as yours in the case where $S$ is finite, if it isn't then to construct a basis in this manner you need to add the quantifier). We claim that the functions $\delta_s$ defined by:
$$\delta_s(x)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }x=s\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
form a basis for $F^S$. We first check these are linearly independent. Let:
$$\sum_{s\in S}x_s\delta_s=0$$
where only finitely many $x_s\neq0$. Now since this is the zero function, it must be zero on all $p\in S$. Evaluating at $p\in S$ we find that:
$$\left(\sum_{s\in S}x_s\delta_s\right)(p)=\sum_{s\in S}x_s\delta_s(p)=x_p=0$$
so each $x_p$ has to be zero for all $p\in S$, it follows that this set of vectors is linearly independent.

We now check that this spans. Let $f\in F^S$, then $f(p)=0$ for all but finitely many $s\in S$. Let $S_f=\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$, then we see that:
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^n f(s_i)\delta_{s_i}$$
as they agree at all points.

Given this, do you think you can apply all this to your situation?